# Get distance from multiple annotations

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios6, core-location, mapkit

I'm been trying for days, and have search the web to try to solve my problem, but I can't find any relevant information.

I'm trying to calculate the distance from userLocation to my annotations in an UITableView, with an CustomCell.

I'm able to get the calculated distances in NSLOG, but in my tableView im getting 0.0km in all of my cells.

Can anyone see what im doing wrong here?

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.mapView.delegate = self;
    [self startLocationServices];

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"points" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSArray *anns = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];

    for(NSMutableDictionary *note in anns) {
        double doubleLatitude = [[note objectForKey:@"sculptureLatitudeKey"] doubleValue];
        double doubleLongitude = [[note objectForKey:@"sculptureLongitudeKey"] doubleValue];
        Annotation* myAnnotation = [[Annotation alloc] init];
        CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate;
        theCoordinate.latitude = doubleLatitude;
        theCoordinate.longitude = doubleLongitude;
        myAnnotation.coordinate = theCoordinate;
        myAnnotation.title = [note objectForKey:@"sculptureNameKey"];
        myAnnotation.subtitle = [note objectForKey:@"sculptureAddressKey"];
        myAnnotation.sculptureIdKey = [note objectForKey:@"sculptureIdKey"];
        [self.mapView addAnnotation:myAnnotation];
    }
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(userLocation.coordinate, 5000, 5000);
    [self.mapView setRegion:[self.mapView regionThatFits:region] animated:YES];
}

- (void)startLocationServices
{
    if (self.locationManager == nil)
    {
        self.locationManager = [CLLocationManager new];
    }
    [self.locationManager setDelegate:self];
    [self.locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
    [self.locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];

    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)stopLocationServices
{
    [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    [self.locationManager setDelegate:nil];
}


- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{    
    for (Annotation *annotation in self.mapView.annotations)
    {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = [annotation coordinate];
        CLLocation *annLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:coord.latitude longitude:coord.longitude];

        CLLocationDistance calculatedDistance = [annLocation distanceFromLocation:newLocation];
        NSLog(@"Nice distance:%.1f m\n", calculatedDistance);
    }
}
```

My NSLOG shows this, and i only have 3 annotations in my .plist

```
2013-02-13 16:46:14.736 TalkingSculpture[91833:c07] Nice distance:762.1 m
2013-02-13 16:46:14.736 TalkingSculpture[91833:c07] Nice distance:98.8 m
2013-02-13 16:46:14.736 TalkingSculpture[91833:c07] Nice distance:2704.3 m
2013-02-13 16:46:14.737 TalkingSculpture[91833:c07] Nice distance:0.0 m
```

My customCell.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface customCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *customTitle;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *customSubTitle;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *distanceLabel;

@end
```

And customCell.m

```
#import "customCell.h"

@implementation customCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end
```

in the table view i populate the cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    customCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (!cell)
    {
        cell = [[customCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.customTitle.text = [[self.locationsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"sculptureNameKey"];
    cell.customSubTitle.text = [[self.locationsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"sculptureAddressKey"];
    cell.distanceLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f km\n", _calulatedDistance];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code that sets the distance in the custom cell?

Comment: Are you formatting the text correctly in the cell? %.1f for example?

Comment: @AnnaKarenina i just updated my question with more code from customCell, and cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: How is `_calulatedDistance` set?  Shouldn't its value be based on the object at the current `indexPath`?

Comment: @AnnaKarenina i don't know what you mean?

Comment: In cellForRowAtIndexPath, the code sets the distanceLabel text to _calulatedDistance.  How is _calulatedDistance's value set?

Comment: @AnnaKarenina It's set in - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation

Comment: In didUpdateToLocation, it is setting a local variable named calculatedDistance which has no connection to the _calulatedDistance being used in cellForRowAtIndexPath.  Are the table view, map view and locationManager all in the same view controller?

Comment: @AnnaKarenina Can i send you my sourcecode or add you to my github repo?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you still need an answer to this.  But every time your table view is displayed you will need to populate an array (or alternative) to hold all the current distances.  Then in cellForRowAtIndexPath set the label to the appropriate distances from that array.  What you are doing in this code is setting it to the ivar, which is either nil or 0 when you are calling it.